# Twitter bootstrap managing multiple radio buttons through Javascript in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap in my rails app, and I am constructing a form with multiple radio button inputs. In order to manage the form data, I have created a hidden field whose value is updated via Javascript.

Sample code below for any given input:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
          <button type="button" class="btn" id="ornamental_only_yes" name="ornamental_only" value="yes">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn" id="ornamental_only_no" name="ornamental_only" value="no">No</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="ornamental_only" name="ornamental_only" value="">
```

Here is the Javascript to manage this event:

```
<script>
  var btns = ['ornamental_only_yes', 'ornamental_only_no'];
  var input = document.getElementById('ornamental_only');
  for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(btns[i]).addEventListener('click', function() {
      input.value = this.value;
    });
  }
</script>
```

My question: Is there a way to abstract the Javascript code in such a way as to apply to multiple radio button inputs simultaneously? (For instance, if I had 3 repetitions of the code block above with different id's)

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Your question is tagged as jQuery, but there isn't any in your example.

Comment: Use jQuery library, Your code is in native javascript. Take a look at my answer

Comment: @ManjunathManohar I think you and moin misunderstood the question. He's asking how to apply this code to multiple *sets* of buttons (extrapolating from this example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume this is your HTML with multiple sets of buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="btn_group_1" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="ornamental_only_yes" name="ornamental_only" value="yes">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="ornamental_only_no" name="ornamental_only" value="no">No</button>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_1" name="ornamental_only" value="">
<div class="btn-group" id="btn_group_2" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="awesome_only_yes" name="awesome_only" value="yes">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="awesome_only_no" name="awesome_only" value="no">No</button>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_2" name="awesome_only" value="">
```

To dynamically listen for clicks on all button groups, you could do something like this (untested jQuery):

```
$('.btn-group .btn').on('click', function() {
    var parentID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('#hidden_' + parentID.substr(parentID.length - 1)).val($(this).val());
});
```

This just targets the hidden `input` fields based on the number at the end of the `id`.

Comment: this works great! Thanks Sara. For this code to work, do I always need id="btn_group_x" as well as the id="hidden_1" values? Or will the code work with just the hidden id incremental values?

Comment: The number at the end of `btn_group_*` will have to match up with the number on `hidden_*` (to indicate that they're grouped together). So yes, you need numbers on both.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= btns.length; i++) {
```

Comment: not sure I follow how adding <= will change the behavior of this javascript. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.

```
var buttonObjs = $(".btn-group").find("button");
buttonObjs.click(function(){
  $("#ornamental_only").val(this.value);  
});
```

To apply this code to multiple blocks, all you need to do is assign a specific class to the btn-group element, something like,

```
<div class="btn-group js_radio_toggle">
```

In the js code just use,

```
var buttonObjs = $(".btn-group.js_radio_toggle").find("button");
```

now this code can be reused anywhere.

also in your js code. you can do this,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("js_radio_toggle").
```

But I would recommend you to use jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, I would upvote this if I could but I don't have enough reputation yet :-/

Comment: $("#ornamental_only").val(this.value); 

does this code mean I need a similar line for each button group? i.e. if I have another button group, I need to specify all the name fields here:

$("#ornamental_only_1").val(this.value);
$("#ornamental_only_2").val(this.value);

etc.